# <BR> is not working and add remove command in this script

Tags: php, jquery

The Code:

```
var i=0,j=0;

var t1= new Array();
function createtext(){

    i++;

    t1[i]=document.createElement('input');

    t1[i].type='text';

    t1[i].name='text'+i;

    t1[i].value = "hello"+i;

    t1[i].size = 10;

    document.forms[0].appendChild(t1[i]);

    var mybr=document.createElement("<br>");

    document.appendChild(mybr);

}
```

The Form:

```
<form action="" method="get" name="f1">

    <input name="b1" type="button" onClick="createtext()" value="+">

</form>
```

When Clicking the "+" button the textbox will generate downward not to the side of each textbox.. then each textbox has a "REMOVE" link in thier side.. when the "REMOVE" was click the textbox will remove.. pls help me.

```
------------------------------------------------
(+) <-imagine this is the button

[SAMPLETEXTBOX1] REMOVE <-imagine a textbox1 with remove link beside it

[SAMPLETEXTBOX2] REMOVE <-imagine a textbox2 with remove link beside it

[SAMPLETEXTBOX1] REMOVE <-imagine a textbox3 with remove link beside it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append to the `form`, not the `document`, also use `document.createElement("br")` instead of `document.createElement("<br>")`.

```
var mybr=document.createElement("br");
document.forms[0].appendChild(mybr);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the addition, you could wrap your input box and text in a DIV which would give you the desired result of the controls showing up below.

Then, when you click the remove you could just remove the DIV element and it could take all of it's child nodes (input and text) with it.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hfdAL/9/

remove the <> from your document.createElement